# kineticjs "cannot call method 'appendChild' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, html, kineticjs

I am only starting to use kineticJS but I am getting some errors after following 
[This](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/labs/html5-canvas-image-mouseover/) tutorial

I don't understand why but I am getting an exception from inside the KineticJS file:

`"Uncaught TypeError: cannot call method 'appendChild' of undefined".`

When I do a step by step `alert()`s, I see that it stops after

> var stage = new Kinetic.Stage("rightSide", 578, 200);

but I most definitively have:

> ```
> <canvas id="rightSide">
> </canvas>
> ```

I also tried:

> ```
> <div id="rightSide">
> </div>
> ```

and I am getting the same error.

Thanks.

Edit:
in response to the comments below, this is Copy-Paste from the tutorial:

> ```
> </head>
> <body>
> <div id="container">
> </div>
> </body>
> ```

Comment: not sure if it is relevant, but in the example the id passed to `Kinetic.Stage` is a container that has canvas elements in it, not the id of the canvas element itself

Comment: i don't see where there's a canvas element inside the div with id container. that's the only tag in the body

Comment: script from the example: `var stage = new Kinetic.Stage("container", 578, 200);` html from the example: `<div id="container"><canvas ...></canvas><canvas ...></canvas>...</div>`

Comment: are you trying to troll me or something.

Comment: no, im posting the code from the link that you put in your question.

Comment: i see now. and i have 2 things to say. the code posted in the tutorial and the actual code running is not the same code. and i solved the problem i'll post an answer. sorry about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a change in Kinetic.Stage constructor since March  https://github.com/ericdrowell/KineticJS/commit/7ced50f6943af544dbdfc95883ec41728db1d3bd

Thus @Gleeb 's own answer reflects current practice in KineticJS v4.0.x instead of those docs / tutorials made in the early v3 era.

---

Should make a pull request for backward compatibility.. something like

```
if(arguments.length>1){
 config.container =  arguments[0];
 config.width = arguments[1];
 config.height = arguments[2];
}
```

... in the Stage constructor.

Answer (score 2):

the problem was with the actual creation of the stage.

instead of

> var stage = new Kinetic.Stage("container", 578, 200);

i did

> var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
>             container: "container",
>             width: 578,
>             height: 200
>           });

Answer (score 1):

Try to run your script at the `window.onload` event (as in the example) and use `console.log()` to debug your variables/objects.

```
window.onload = function() {
  var stage = new Kinetic.Stage("rightSide", 578, 200);
  console.log('stage =', stage); // DEBUG
};
```

...and use the `div` and not the `canvas`.

```
<div id="rightSide"></div>
```

You´ll find more tutorials and the official API documentation at http://www.kineticjs.com/docs/symbols/Kinetic.Stage.php

Comment: i need to decide what answer to approve yours or mine.
can you explain why using window.onload is better than $(document).ready of jquery? because what i have posted actually solved it.

Comment: Your question doesn´t say anything about jQuery but I would recommend using document ready if it´s available. What´s important is that the DOM has finished loading before you´re trying to access it.